# Is it possible to use a hyphen/dash as a variable in Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and have wrote a simple script to send plaint txt emails via SMTP (Ref: https://realpython.com/python-send-email/). I was wondering if I would be able to in some way include a hyphen as variable name but i'm not having any luck seeing if it's possible. My understanding is that you are cannot use hyphens in python but is there a work around?

The idea is to be able to apply a region as an addtional parameter of the smtp host, however, the regions in aws regions can be quite long to type, so abbreviated would have been great.

For ex. `email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` is one of the regions in AWS, could this be used as just `ap-southeast-2` ?

```
python3 send-email.py -username -password --region ap-southeast-2
```

I've got everything working but just this.. Open to ideas too!

Comment: Why would you need that to be a variable name? Command line arguments are strings, not variables.

Comment: no, you cannot use hyphens in variable names, but `ap-southeast-2` looks like an argument (string) to your script, what's the need for creating a variable with that exact name?

Comment: I'm very new to Python and any programming language in all honesty. Getting this to work was a miracle in itself. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot use a hyphen in a variable or parameter name. You are restricted to the following rules

#### 1st character

`'_a-zA-Z'`
You can start a variable name using any letter or an underscore

#### All other characters

`'[_a-zA-Z0-9]*'`
Same as first character, plus numbers.

#### Why?

The hyphen is the subtraction operator. Imagine you tried to create a function `is-even(foo)`:

```py
def is-even(foo):
    return('bar')
```

To python interpreters, it looks like you are trying to define a function of the keyword `is` minus some function `even` with the param `foo`. This type of response would be nearly impossible to avoid, hence hyphens are disallowed from variable and function names in nearly all languages.